# elastic search query term returns all the data

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to query my ES, here is my data,
you can just run this in sense, it creates index fst and fills it with 4 items.
then you can see that it returns the wrong result number
i want only one result, as should be the case.

```
PUT fst/objects/ggg
{
    "frameAttributes": {
    "identities": [
     { "_id": "DSC00263",   "_score": 0.655822},
     { "_id": "DSC00262",   "_score": 0.59957 },
     { "_id": "DSC00244",   "_score": 0.220819},
     { "_id": "DSC00300",   "_score": 0.191191},
     {"_id": "DSC00276",    "_score": 0.124561}

    ]
    }
}
PUT fst/objects/ffffff
 {
   "frameAttributes": {
    "identities": [
         {"_id": "DSC00222","_score": 0.191009},
         {"_id": "DSC00261","_score": 0.146157},
         {"_id": "DSC00329","_score": 0.14518},
         {"_id": "DSC00225","_score": 0.12622},
         {"_id": "DSC00295","_score": 0.12396}
      ]
   }

}
PUT fst/objects/aaaa
 {
   "frameAttributes": {
       "identities": [
         {"_id": "DSC00229","_score": 0.223149},
         {"_id": "DSC00240","_score": 0.178388},
         {"_id": "DSC00228","_score": 0.173769},
         {"_id": "DSC00257","_score": 0.166746},
         {"_id": "DSC00226","_score": 0.153071}
      ]
   }
 }
put fst/objects/abcdef
{
   "frameAttributes": {
     "identities": [
         { "_id": "DSC00262","_score": 0.427957},
         {"_id": "DSC00263","_score": 0.408772},
         {"_id": "DSC00282","_score": 0.284546 },
         { "_id": "DSC00283","_score": 0.191374},
         {"_id": "DSC00299", "_score": 0.165478}
      ]
   }
}
```

My Query should return only one result

```
get fst/_search
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
           "frameAttributes.identities._id": {
              "value": "DSC00229"
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a while
but I learned something new elastic search doesn't like you to create a fields called _id. I changed it to personId and now it just works.

Thanks all :)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to set the required field as `not_analyzed`. In your case, the field is `_id`. You can do that while creating the index. For example:

```
PUT /gb/_mapping/tweet
{
  "properties" : {
    "tag" : {
      "type" :    "string",
      "index":    "not_analyzed"
    }
  }
}
```

Check this link for reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_exact_values.html